# how to find word or phrase that starts with a sequence in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Lets say I have these data

```
[
    {
        name: "Apple Company"
    },
    {
        name: "Microsoft Company"
    }
]
```

I want to get the query results like this:

query 1:

```
name: apple
```

result 1:

```
[
    {
        name: "Apple Company"
    }
]
```

query 2:

```
name: app
```

result 2:

```
[
    {
        name: "Apple Company"
    }
]
```

query 3:

```
name: apple com
```

result 3:

```
[
    {
        name: "Apple Company"
    }
]
```

query 4:

```
name: apple company
```

result 4:

```
[
    {
        name: "Apple Company"
    }
]
```

query 5:

```
name: company
```

result 5:

```
[
    {
        name: "Apple Company"
    },
    {
        name: "Microsoft Company"
    }
]
```

query 6:

```
name: ap com
```

result 6:

```
[]
```

How to do it in elasticsearch?

Comment: You're talking about [completion suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html#completion-suggester).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Shingle Token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-shingle-tokenfilter.html) and prefix query from the elasticsearch which will cover all the scenario you have mentioned in question:

**Index Mapping:**

```json
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "english": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "my_shingle_filter",
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "my_shingle_filter": {
          "type": "shingle",
          "min_shingle_size": 2,
          "max_shingle_size": 4,
          "output_unigrams": true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "english"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Query:**

```json
{
  "query": {
    "prefix": {
      "name": {
        "value": "apple com"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `query_string` to search your data.

Index your data via Kibana DevTools.

```
POST test_autocomplete/_bulk
{"index":{}}
{"id":1,"name":"Apple Company"}
{"index":{}}
{"id":2,"name":"Microsoft Company"}
```

---

Search your data with query_string.

```
GET test_autocomplete/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "name",
      "query": "app* or mic*"
    }
  }
}
```

---

You can also use [match_bool_prefix](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-bool-prefix-query.html) query

```
GET test_autocomplete/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_bool_prefix" : {
      "name": "co"
    }
  }
}
```

Reference for query_string: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html

Reference for autocomplete: https://opster.com/guides/elasticsearch/how-tos/elasticsearch-auto-complete-guide/

Here is the result for the match_bool_prefix query.
[image]